# App integration with google now

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-voice, google-now

I'm developing an android app. The app starts a background service for user monitoring and it has the possibility to start the service via main activity or via widget and it works great. I'd like to have a little integration with google now to start the service. Now I can only open the app via google now, but I want to start/stop the service instead (via google now). How can I do?

Comment: "now i can open the app via google now" can u explain this line more. i might have miss taken u ?

Comment: I meant: with google now you can say "open [app]". This works but it opens my main activity, I want to start my background service instead.

Comment: ru speaking things like voice recogniser or speech recogniser, post some code where ur opening main activity of the app. so that i can help u out.

Comment: I haven't got any code to post! The command "open [app]" is a built-in command for google now, you don't need to do anything special in your app, it simply opens your apo via main activity.

Comment: i think u cannot do that. u should build one more app which intern runs ur service. Google might be looking directly for launcher intent and opening ur app. Service it wont even understand.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**update**

i think you cannot do that. u should build one more app which intern runs ur service. Google might be looking directly for launcher intent and opening your app.  Google  service wont even come to know or understand that you have some service that needs to be run.

Comment: I can't see google now integration in this tutorial. The app already works and it's complete.